# pkg install: Chain was rooted in an untrusted self-signed certificate

Tags: package-management, solaris-11

I am trying to install GUI Environment in Oracle Solaris 11.3 but when I executed command

```
# pkg install solaris-desktop
```

I got following error

```
Creating Plan (Package planning:  25/362): -
pkg install: Chain was rooted in an untrusted self-signed certificate.
The package involved is pkg://solaris/library/python/pyatspi-27@2.30.0,5.11-11.4.0.0.1.9.0:20180618T175853Z
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. The reason was that I was using Repos for 11.4 in Solaris 11.3. When I installed repos for verion 11.3, the issue was resolved.

Comment: How did you change the repo version from 11.4 to 11.3?  Can you update the solution with that info?